# Radix JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-theme

I am using the Radix Bootstrap Theme and Drupal 9.1.5. I have a Navigation Block with Children (using Bootstrap Dropdown) and some JS in radix_aur_scipt.js. I use that JS to open a Bootstrap Modal

```
import 'bootstrap';

...

  function createPdfModal (element) {   
    ...       
    $('.modal').modal();    
  }
```

To use that JS I import bootstrap.min.js with Webpack

```
mix.js('src/js/radix_aur.script.js', 'js');
mix.copy('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'assets/js');
```

And radix_aur.libraries.yml

```
  js:
    assets/js/radix_aur.script.js: {}
    assets/js/bootstrap.min.js: {}
```

When I am logged in as admin everything works as expected (Dropdown opens, Modal opens). As a non admin user I cant open the dropdown in the navigation. So I imported bootstrap.bundle.min.js in webpack assuming that popper.js was missing. I forgott to change that in the radix_aur.libraries.yml which then didnt deliver bootstrap at all. However that fixed the problem with the dropdown for non admin users but then I cant open the modal

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
```

When I realized my mistacke I changed the radix_aur.libraries.yml that fixed the problem for the modal but then I am left with not beeing able to open the dropdown as non admin. I also tried using bootstrap.min.js and popper.js with the same outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were one additional import in the radix_aur_script.js

```
import bootstrap
```

I deleted that and then everything worked as expected with the bootstrap.bundle.min.js
Still dont know why this would block the whole thing from working.